# Problem with superfish submenu being trimmed by content in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

Greetings, I have a problem which would seem to involve some kind of z-index issue, but for a change it's in everything **except** IE.

If you take a look at http://cougar.motivo.com.au/ in anything except Internet Explorer and hover over the last menu item "Contact Us" you can see what I'm referring to. Basically the supersub menu appears to be being trimmed by the width of the element below it.

You can see via the source that I've tried setting z-indexes & position:relative, but at this point I'm stumped. Any and all input would be gratefully received :)

*P.S. I am aware that there are still a couple of issues in IE6. I am yet to have the pleasure of addressing those (groans).*

Comment: For the sake of anyone else who may have this problem, I found another solution to that presented by griegs below, which ended up introducing other issues related to position: absolute. The other solution is to introduce some padding to the side of the container element which has the issue. Then the menu is no longer trimmed as it is still 'part of the page'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the contact us menu is part of the page and as such is being trimmed when outside of it.  if you put it higher, or use position: absolute and then place that should fix the issue.

can happen i guess if your, let's say div, is inside another.  breaking the div out and moving it higher up will normally fix it.